# Developing Outlook addin for Mac

Tags: macos, outlook, office365, outlook-addin

I have already created an addin for Ms Outlook in Windows using visual studio 2010 and C#. It works fine with Ms Outlook 2007,2010,2013 and 2016 on Windows.

Now I would like to create the same addin for Outlook on Mac. I have downloaded a .pkg file of Outlook for Mac and have installed it. For activating It needs a Office 365 subscription and I have subscribed a one month free trial period.

Now to build the addin, I have surfed the internet.But I have not found any proper post related to this topic. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

.NET/COM add-ins built with Visual Studio do not work on Outlook for Mac.  Only the new web Outlook Add-ins (using JavaScript + HTML5 + CSS) will work.  See: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins

Answer (score 1):

Outlook for Mac does not support plug-ins as @Eric said. you could use office 365  apps([Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) ) or  There are ways to add limited functionality to Outlook via AppleScript.